# How can I search functions that may be indirectly affected by a modification in a common library function in .NET?

Tags: c#, regression

Suppose I have simple function in a shared library that returns a value:

```
public int foo_function(int a) {
    //(some arcane logic based on input a)
    return b
}
```

in Visual Studio find all references will return the immediate callers of `foo_function()`.

However if the callers of this function are also common functions that also perform some logic as well on the result of `foo_function`, I have to do a find all references for each of these functions. Repeat the same for the 3rd degree, 4th degree, 5th degree and so on. How can I perform a search that will trace all impacted code should there be a change in `foo_function()`?

Comment: Its possibly not the easiest approach, but, could unit testing help with seeing if changing a function causes your code to break?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow*

Comment: If you change the public interface the compiler will tell you. If you only change the implementation then how would a tool know if the change is a different algorithm altogether or just a refactor. I guess a simple file watcher will do the job.

Comment: @KenWhite ok thanks for the info. Didn't know that. I have rephrased the question.

Comment: This is called a "caller graph", and many documentation tools can generate one.  `doxygen` can for sure (and does support C# code).  You may also be able to generate caller graphs from assemblies (without source code) using RedGate Reflector and alternatives like dotPeek.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual studio 2015, there is a feature called as codelens. If you look on top of function signature. it shows references to this function from all places in the code base.
If you hover over this and click on "show on code map", it shows all possible areas it will affect if this function is changed.

Hope this helps.